# Edge case for finding strictly increasing squares of a number

Tags: algorithm, recursion, callstack

I'm trying to solve this codewars kata, [Square into Squares](https://www.codewars.com/kata/square-into-squares-protect-trees/train/javascript).

I'm passing most of the tests, but there are two inputs for which my algorithm exceeds the maximum call stack size.

I feel like I'm taking care of all the edge conditions, and I can't figure out what I'm missing.

```js
function sumSquares (n) {
  function decompose (num, whatsLeft, result) {
    if (whatsLeft === 0) return result
    else {
      if (whatsLeft < 0 || num === 0) return null
      else {
        return decompose(num-1, whatsLeft - num * num, [num].concat(result)) || decompose(num-1, whatsLeft, result)
      }
    }
  }
  return decompose(n-1, n*n, [])
}

const resA = sumSquares(50) //[1,3,5,8,49]
console.log(resA)
const resB = sumSquares(7) //[2,3,6]
console.log(resB)
const resC = sumSquares(11) //[ 1, 2, 4, 10 ]
console.log(resC)

const res1 = sumSquares(90273)
console.log(res1)
const res2 = sumSquares(123456)
console.log(res2)
```

Comment: Have you considered using a memoisation based solution ? It would decrease the pressure on your call stack significantly....
https://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php

Comment: No I have not... so the logic is fine then, I need to memoize? That's cool, I'll give it a go.

Comment: It appears to me that your current program doesn't solve the problem.  What output do you get for your test cases?

Comment: @Prune for sumSquares(90273) and sumSquares(123456) I get no output, the max call stack is exceeded...

Comment: And your other test cases?  Your posted code has only one, and no output.

Comment: I'll help with this a little later, if you haven't received a nice answer by then ^^

Comment: @IsabellaChen : please update if you have successfully solved your problem using memoization :)

Comment: @RannLifshitz memoization only helps this problem if you're looking for more than one solution, which is not applicable to this particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is correct, but has two problems: first, your call stack will eventually reach size "num" (which may be causing your failure for large inputs), and second, it may recompute the same values multiple times.

The first problem is easy to fix: you can skip `num` values which give a negative `whatsLeft` result. Like this:

```
while(num * num > whatsLeft) num = num - 1;
```

You can insert this after the first `if` statement. This also enables you to remove the check for negative `whatsLeft`. As a matter of style, I removed the `else{}` cases for your if statements after a return -- this reduces the indentation and (I think) makes the code easier to read. But that's just a matter of personal taste.

```
function sumSquares (n) {
  function decompose (num, whatsLeft, result) {
    if (whatsLeft === 0) return result;
    while (num * num > whatsLeft) num -= 1;
    if (num === 0) return null;
    return decompose(num-1, whatsLeft - num * num, [num].concat(result)) || decompose(num-1, whatsLeft, result);
  }
  return decompose(n-1, n*n, []);
}
```

Your test cases run instantly for me with these changes, so the second problem (which would be solved by memoization) isn't necessary to address. I also tried submitting it on the codewars site, and with a little tweaking (the outer function needs to be called `decompose`, so both the outer and inner functions need renaming), all 113 test cases pass in 859ms.

Answer (score 1):

@PaulHankin's answer offers good insight

Let's look at `sumSquares (n)` where `n = 100000`

```js
decompose (1e5 - 1, 1e5 * 1e5, ...)
```

In the first frame,

```js
num = 99999
whatsLeft = 10000000000
```

Which spawns

```js
decompose (99999 - 1, 1e10 - 99999 * 99999, ...)
```

Where the second frame is

```js
num = 99998
whatsLeft = 199999
```

And here's the problem: `num * num` above is *significantly* larger than `whatsLeft` and each time we recur to try a new `num` that first, we only decrease by `-1` each frame. Without fixing anything, the next process spawned will be

```js
decompose (99998 - 1, 199999 - 99998 * 99998, ...)
```

Where the third frame is

```js
num = 99997
whatsLeft = -9999500005
```

See how `whatsLeft` is *significantly* negative? It means we'll have to decrease `num` by a lot before the next value doesn't cause `whatsLeft` to drop below zero

```js
// [frame #4]
num = 99996
whatsLeft = -9999000017

// [frame #5]
num = 99995   
whatsLeft = -9998800026

...

// [frame #99552]
num = 448
whatsLeft = -705

// [frame #99553]
num = 447
whatsLeft = 190
```

As we can see above, it would take almost 100000 frames just to guess the second digit of `sumSquares (100000)`. This is exactly what Paul Hankin describes as your first problem.

We can also visualize it a little easer if we only look at `decompose` with `num`. Below, if a solution cannot be found, the stack will grow to size `num` and therefore cannot be used to compute solutions where `num` exceeds the stack limit

```js
// imagine num = 100000
function decompose (num, ...) {
  ...
  decompose (num - 1 ...) || decompose (num - 1, ...)
}
```

Paul's solution uses a `while` loop to decrement `num` using a loop until `num` is small enough. Another solution would involve calculating the next `guess` by finding the square root of the remaining `whatsLeft`

```js
const sq = num * num
const next = whatsLeft - sq
const guess = Math.floor (Math.sqrt (next))
return decompose (guess, next, ...) || decompose (num - 1, whatsLeft, ...)
```

Now it can be used to calculate values where `num` is huge

```js
console.log (sumSquares(123456))
// [ 1, 2, 7, 29, 496, 123455 ]
```

But notice there's a bug for certain inputs. The squares of the solution still sum to the correct amount, but it's allowing some numbers to be repeated

```js
console.log (sumSquares(50))
// [ 1, 1, 4, 9, 49 ]
```

To enforce the *strictly increasing* requirement, we have to ensure that a calculated guess is still lower than the previous. We can do that using `Math.min`

```js
const guess = Math.floor (Math.sqrt (next))
const guess = Math.min (num - 1, Math.floor (Math.sqrt (next)))
```

Now the bug is fixed

```js
console.log (sumSquares(50))
// [ 1, 1, 4, 9, 49 ]
// [ 1, 3, 5, 8, 49 ]
```

Full program demonstration

```js
function sumSquares (n) {
  function decompose (num, whatsLeft, result) {
    if (whatsLeft === 0)
      return result;
      
    if (whatsLeft < 0 || num === 0)
      return null;
    
    const sq = num * num
    const next = whatsLeft - sq
    const guess = Math.min (num - 1, Math.floor (Math.sqrt (next)))
    
    return decompose(guess, next, [num].concat(result)) || decompose(num-1, whatsLeft, result);
  }
  return decompose(n-1, n*n, []);
}

console.log (sumSquares(50))
// [ 1, 3, 5, 8, 49 ]

console.log (sumSquares(123456))
// [ 1, 2, 7, 29, 496, 123455 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make this enlightening answer! :)

Comment: @IsabellaChen you're very welcome. Your initial program is very good and demonstrates you have a good way of thinking about the problem.